# Getting started with NHibernate 3.2 Loquacious API

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm starting a new project and I want to use NHibernate 3.2. I know that it can now do something similar to FluentNHibernate and I want to give it a try.

But I am having a hard time finding documentation on the Loquacious API. I've seen [blog](http://slynetblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/getting-started-with-nhibernate-and.html) [posts](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/me-on-fluent-nhibernate.html) on how to configure the ISessionFactory, but I'm getting lost after this. I know that the 3.2 API is moving fast and that article about 3 to 4 months old are already out of date, but I'm looking for the most recent information.

Where can I find the resources concerning:

- How to setup NHibernate 3.2 without using XML, without using FluentNHibernate and without using ConfORM?
- How to register the mappings?
- How to create conventions?

Please remember that this is concerning NHibernate 3.2 (and probably above). If any of the concepts like mappings and conventions no longer apply, please can you point me into the right direction?

I have some experience with NHibernate and FluentNHibernate as I used them for a small project, but it was not very complicated.

Comment: You may get a better response if you ask this question on [link](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers) nhuser.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm already trying to fill that hole in mapping-by-code documentation and examples with the series of posts on my blog. I'm trying to see what is supported and to compare mapping-by-code possibilities with Fluent NHibernate. Here are the posts:

1. [First impressions](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-first.html)
2. [Naming convention resembling Fluent](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-naming-convention.html)
3. [Property](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html)
4. [Component](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-component-and-odd-cases.html)
5. [ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html)
6. [inheritance](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-inheritance.html)
7. [dynamic component](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-dynamic-component.html)
8. [Set and Bag](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html)
9. [OneToMany and other collection-based relation types](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetomany-and-other.html)
10. [concurrency](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-concurrency.html)
11. [OneToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetoone.html)
12. [Join](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-join.html)
13. [Any](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-any.html)
14. [List, Array, IdBag](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-list-array-idbag.html)
15. [Map](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-map.html)
16. [Id, NaturalId](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-id-naturalid.html)
17. [composite identifiers](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-composite-identifiers.html)
18. [entity-level mappings](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-entity-level-mappings.html)
19. [**the summary**](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html)

Comment: thanks for this! You have given me the confidence to make the switch from FNH. I started with hbm.xml then switched to FNH and corrupted my hbm.xml knowledge. Now I feel I need to relearn the hbm.xml to use the mapping-by-code. lol.

Answer (score 8):

I created a video for just this and posted it on youtube, you can find the link to it [here](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/lessons/FreeCSharpLessons.aspx), see Lesson 13.  You can also download the source code [here](http://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/lessons/FreeCSharpLessonsSource2.aspx).  I hope they provide the information you are searching for.