# nHibernate 3.2 database config in code?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

NHibernate seems to have some new ways to map entities in code, which is really nice, but I can't find any information about configuring the database connections in code.  It has been a while since I used NHibernate (version 2) and I am used to Fluent NHibernate which provides this capability.  Is there a similar feature built into NHibernate 3.2 and if so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the newer alternative to Fluent NHibernate available in version 3.2 has been dubbed the 'Loquacious API'. See this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348670/getting-started-with-nhibernate-3-2-loquacious-api) and the nhibernate forge wiki [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/a-fully-working-skeleton-for-sexy-loquacious-nh.aspx) for examples on how to use it.

Comment: hmmm? which one of those mention 'loquacious' database connections?

Comment: Check out James Kovacs' blog http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2011/01/21/loquacious-configuration-in-nhibernate-3/

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say exactly what you want to configure, but this might get you started. Explore with intellisense to see more options.

```
var config = new Configuration()
            .Proxy(p => p.ProxyFactoryFactory<NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory>())
            .DataBaseIntegration(d =>
                                     {
                                         d.ConnectionString = "foo";
                                         d.Dialect<SQLiteDialect>();
                                     });
```

Comment: My code shows how the set the ConnectionString and Dialect. What else do you need to configure?