# nhibernate 3.3 sql server configuration

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate

I googled it but I couldn't find any working example how to configure nhibernate 3.3 by code. Here is what I could find but it doesn't work, it throws the exception "The user must provide an ADO.NET connection"

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.DataBaseIntegration(c=> c.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>());
cfg.SetProperty("hibernate.connection.connection_string", "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
    .SetProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver")
    .SetProperty("hibernate.connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");

var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
mapper.Class<User>(map =>
{
    map.Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.Guid));
    map.Property(x => x.UserName);
});
var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingFor(new Type[] { typeof(User) });

cfg.AddDeserializedMapping(mapping, "test");

var factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

var session = factory.OpenSession();

session.SaveOrUpdate(new User() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), UserName = "Hello" });

session.Flush();
session.Close();
factory.Close();
```

What is wrong? What is missing? Where I can find a working example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The new fluent NHibernate configuration is called Loquacious. You can find [an introduction to it](http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2011/01/21/loquacious-configuration-in-nhibernate-3/) on [James Kovacs](http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/author/jameskovacs/) blog.

Also, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348670/getting-started-with-nhibernate-3-2-loquacious-api). It has a collection of links, mostly for mapping by code functionality:

[Getting started with NHibernate 3.2 Loquacious API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348670/getting-started-with-nhibernate-3-2-loquacious-api)

As for your configuration, you don't need to use .SetProperty() calls to initialize database connection. Instead, use something like this:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.DataBaseIntegration(c=> 
    {
       c.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>());
       c.ConnectionString = 
           "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    }
```